# Can't return appended value from within a Python process

Tags: python, list, process, append

I am running Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 8.10.

For a project I am working on, I need to run several processes concurrently and save each of their outputs into their own respective lists. Since I can't return the output value directly from the process, I am passing the output list as an argument to my target function and appending the output to that list. The problem is that when I try to access that list after running the process, the list is still empty. A simplified version of the problem I'm having is below along with the error message.

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys, math, os,commands

outputs = []

def calculate(a,b,outputs):
    c = a*b
    outputs.append(c)
    #return c

outputs1 = []

p1 = Process(target = calculate, args = (2,3,outputs1))

p1.start()
p1.join()

print 'len(outputs1) = ' + str(len(outputs1))

print 'outputs1 = ' + str(outputs1[0])
```

Error:

```
len(outputs1) = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "append_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    print 'outputs1 = ' + str(outputs1[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to keep each process completely independent of the others for fear of corrupting data. I've looked into trying to use the Array module from multiprocessing, but it appears that append is specific to lists. When I run the exact same code with Thread instead of Process, I get the desired output with no problem, which leads me to believe this is an issue of memory sharing.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting - it is especially important for Python code to see how things are indented.

Comment: Using something like AMPQ would make it easy to distribute work among serveral machines.

Comment: Have you considered using `multiprocessing.Queue`s?

Answer (score 3):

When you use separate processes, each process gets its own copy of everything in memory. That's why the parent process never sees anything in its `outputs`: each child process is appending to its own copy of `outputs`.

You need to use some form of interprocess communication. Python's [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) library supplies two features for this: [pipes and queues](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

For example, using a `Queue`:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
>>> def f(q): q.put("hello from the child process")
... 
>>> q = Queue()
>>> p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
>>> p.start()
>>> p.join()
>>> q.get()
'hello from the child process'
```

Comment: In a subsection titled "Joining processes that use queues" of the [Programming Guidelines - All Platforms](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms) for the `multiprocessing` module, it recommends "that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined". I believe that means the `q.get()` in the code for this answer should b moved to *before* the `p.join()` like they show in the example in the docs.

Comment: Good point. (The docs might mention this in the section on pipes and queues, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The section titled [*Exchanging objects between processes*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)  in the in the online documentation of the`multiprocessing`module says that it [only] "supports two types of communication channel between processes" and goes on to mention **Queues** and **Pipes**. Notably it does *not* mention`list`objects like`outputs1`. This makes sense because the two processes don't share memory AFAIK.

I'm not sure, but I also suspect you might need to put the section of your code that creates the process and starts it, etc inside of an`if __name__ == '__main__':`clause to prevent the subprocess from creating a sub-subprocess.

In summary, I think you're going to have to rework things to use one of those two for interprocess communications -- Queues seem like the logical choice to me.